# Matlab Mass spring system: given code unable to run and returning errors

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations

I am starting a project that covers modeling a mass spring system in MatLab. In this lab, we've been provided with some initial code to run in a .m file. According to the video instructions for the project, the code should run without any modification or edits. However, when I run the code, numerous errors are returned.

The code:

```
 function LAB08ex1
m = 1;                                     % mass [kg]
k = 4;                                     % spring constant [N/m]
omega0 = sqrt(k/m);
y0 = 0.1; v0 = 0;                          % initial conditions
[t,Y] = ode45(@f,[0,10],[y0,v0],[],omega0); % solve for 0<t<10
y = Y(:,1); v = Y(:,2);                    % retrieve y, v from Y
figure(1); plot(t,y,'b+-',t,v,'ro-');      % time series for y and v
grid on  
%legend('y(t)','v(t)=y''(t)');              % note the use of '' for '
%figure(2); plot(y,v);                      % phase plot
%xlabel('y'); ylabel('v=y'''); grid on
%-----------------------------------------
function dYdt = f(t,Y,omega0)
y = Y(1); v = Y(2);
dYdt = [ v ; -omega0^2*y ];
```

Running this code returns the following errors:

```
LAB08ex1
Index exceeds array bounds.  
Error in LAB08ex1>f (line 15) y = Y(1); v = Y(2);  
Error in ode45 (line 273) k_(:,1)=feval(FUN,x,t);  
Error in LAB08ex1 (line 6) [t,Y] = ode45(@f,[0,10],[y0,v0],[],omega0);
```

What is going wrong and how should I fix it?

Comment: I've copy-pasted and it run without errors (Matlab 2017b). According to your output, it looks like the function ODE45 in your Matlab's version is different from the latest Matlab version. The only way to fix it is to type `help ODE45`, read documentation and call it differently

Comment: Thank you. Do you know where I can download the latest version of ODE45?

Comment: Thank you so much! I was using a different ODE45. After switching it, the code works.